# Is it possible to programmatically assign jobs to Heroku workers in rails?

Tags: heroku, variable-assignment, manual, worker

I know we can manually run rake tasks in heroku worker processes.
But what if I have 3 workers and I want to programmatically distribute tasks among these workers.